# How can I use 'not in' and 'null' together?

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT last_response
FROM   bank_payments
WHERE  fk_bank_id = 2
       AND creation_timestamp BETWEEN
           '2015-12-16 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-16 11:00:00'
       AND last_response NOT IN ( -2, 0, 152 )
        OR last_response IS NULL;
```

What I'm trying to say here, apart from the timestamp and such, is this: return rows where `last_response` is:

- Not equal to `-2`, `0`, or `152`, or
- Is equal to null

This query takes a very long time to finish, and I'm guessing I'm putting it the wrong way. What is the right way of querying for rows that are not equal to some values, or are `null`?

Comment: whatever you do, if you use AND n OR together, best to wrap in parentheses, like `AND (last_response NOT IN ( -2, 0, 152 )
        OR last_response IS NULL);`  ... or whatever your intention is

Comment: and look at composite or covering indexes. Like rocket fuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend this:

```
SELECT last_response
FROM   bank_payments
WHERE  fk_bank_id = 2
       AND creation_timestamp BETWEEN
           '2015-12-16 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-16 11:00:00'
       AND (last_response NOT IN ( -2, 0, 152 ) OR last_response IS NULL);
```

This adds clarity for the reader and DB that you want data between a certain timestamp for bank id 2. Additionally last response can have no value, or if it has value it should not be 0, -2, 152.

To speed up the query, check indexes on the table. You can create an index, if not already present, on last_response like so:

```
create index idx_bank_payments_last_response on bank_payments(last_response);

explain select ...
```

will give you an explanation of how MySQL hopes to retrieve data and what index it will leverage. Based on that you can opt to change the index to a covering index like so:

```
create index idx_bank_payments_id_ts_lr
on bank_payments (
  last_response,
  fk_bank_id,
  creation_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the executed order of `AND` and `OR` you should use parentheses around the term of last_responses.

```
  SELECT last_response
  FROM bank_payments
  WHERE fk_bank_id = 2
        AND creation_timestamp BETWEEN
        '2015-12-16 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-16 11:00:00'
        AND (last_response NOT IN (-2, 0, 152)
             OR last_response IS NULL);
```

Currently, you are looking for anything where `last_response IS NULL` or the other condititions combined applied.

If you are curious, check both execution plans to see what really happens.